# Insert SuperColumn in Cassandra using thrift

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift

I need some clear examples how I can insert super columns in super column using thrift and java.

Comment: I recommend you use one of the higher-level clients, not raw Thrift. See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions. And presumably you mean insert a supercolumn into a columnfamily? or a column into a supercolumn?

Comment: There are some examples in [this thread](http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/how-to-insert-a-supercolumn-with-java-td4451521.html)

Comment: I need to work with only thrift. I don't want using hector. Thank you for the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public void insertAllReportsByHost(Map<String, List<IReport>> hostReports) throws DatabaseException {
    try {
        Cassandra.Client client = getClient();

        Map<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>> mutationsMap = new HashMap<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<IReport>> entryReport : hostReports.entrySet()) {

            ByteBuffer host = toByteBuffer(entryReport.getKey());
            List<IReport> reports = entryReport.getValue();
            Map<String, List<Mutation>> keyMutations = new HashMap<String, List<Mutation>>();
            List<Mutation> mutations = new ArrayList<Mutation>();

            for (IReport report : reports) {
                report.getProperties();
                Column reportDataColumn = new Column(toByteBuffer("Report Data"));
                reportDataColumn.setValue(toByteBuffer(report.toString()));//TODO make another way
                reportDataColumn.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

                Long nano = System.nanoTime();
                SuperColumn superColumn = new SuperColumn(toByteBuffer(report.getReportId().toString()), Arrays.asList(reportDataColumn));
                ColumnOrSuperColumn col = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
                col.super_column = superColumn;

                Mutation m = new Mutation();
                m.setColumn_or_supercolumn(col);

                mutations.add(m);
            }


            keyMutations.put(COLUMN_FAMILY, mutations);

            mutationsMap.put(host, keyMutations);
        }

        client.batch_mutate(mutationsMap, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    } catch (UnavailableException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    } catch (TException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    } catch (TimedOutException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    }
}
```